# insert given HTML code into a div section with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have several HTML code combinations like this:

```
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<iframe></iframe>
<hr/>
```

and from that I want to create such a code with jQuery:

```
<div id="sample">
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
<hr/>
```

I could just perform these functions:

```
$('h2').before('<div id="sample">');
$('iframe').after('</div>')
```

but these functions doesn't insert only given text, it creats new div sections.
I need to put particular parts of HTML into one div section with a help of jQuery because my page contains many of these combinations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to wrap around groups of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217654/use-jquery-to-wrap-around-groups-of-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('h2').nextUntil('hr').andSelf().wrap('<div class="sample">');
```

Answer (score 4):

​You can use [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select sibling elements up to one matching a selector, and [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap the entire matched set in another element. You need to use `andSelf` to add the original `h2` element back into the matched set:

```
​$("h2").nextUntil("hr").andSelf().wrapAll("<div id='sample'>");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work - div sections with id=sample aren't created

Comment: but if I perform function $("h2").nextUntil("hr").andSelf().css() it works, what is wrong with that wrapAll

Comment: finally I got everything working, Error Console was showing that at the end of this jQuery code exists illegal character, which I guess was copy-paste fault. Also I don't need wrapAll() but simply wrap() function to create seperated div sections. As more than one similar div sections are needed, id can't be used, so in place of id should be class